# What is the equation for combining standardized mean differences across multiple studies?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, standard-error, meta-analysis, group-differences

I am trying to come up with a combined/pooled standardized mean difference for meta-analysis of a dozen or so studies that have the same binary predictive groups and the same continuous outcome measure.

I am able to retrieve the sample size, the mean, and the standard deviation for the control and experimental group in each study, which several sources such as Chochrane Reviews (http://130.226.106.152/openlearning/html/modA1-3.htm) have said I need -- but I can't find any resources that explain what to do with those values.

Here is some fake sample data similar to what I have, in case it is useful for example purposes:

```
Study, Treatment N, Treatment Mean, Treatment SD, Control N, Control Mean, Control SD
A, 30, 15.5, 3.2, 31, 17.9, 3.0
B, 60, 17.3, 1.1, 60, 18.2, 0.9
C, 40, 15.1, 3.5, 44, 18.0, 2.8
```

Comment: It is not appropriate to combine standardized estimates unless the standard deviations are all the same (in which case standardization makes no difference).  Standardized effects have come under much fire in the single study setting.  In meta analysis things get worse.

Comment: Is there an appropriate alternative?

Comment: Meta analysis typically uses random effects models without normalization but allowing for heterogeneity across studies.  There are books on the subject.  It is best by far to have the raw data.  If you have only summary statistics such as means, N, SD you can still do some meta analysis but you will have more unexplained variation without patient-level covariates.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the raw data.  But thank you very much for the advice - I will look into a random effects model.

Comment: @ Frank I think that standardized effect-sizes can be used for a meta-analysis. (see Hedges and Olkin 1985).

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach for such a meta-analysis is to compute an "effect size" for each study that reflects the size (and the direction) of the group difference. If the same continuous variable was measured in each study, then you can stick with raw units and just compute the mean difference for each study. In addition, we need to compute (estimate) the corresponding sampling variance of each mean difference. For the example data you provided, you can easily do this with R and the *metafor* package:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- data.frame(study=c("A", "B", "C"), 
                  n1i=c(30, 60, 40), m1i=c(15.5, 17.3, 15.1), sd1i=c(3.2, 1.1, 3.5), 
                  n2i=c(31, 60, 44), m2i=c(17.9, 18.2, 18.0), sd2i=c(3.0, 0.9, 2.8))    
dat <- escalc(m1i=m1i, sd1i=sd1i, n1i=n1i, 
              m2i=m2i, sd2i=sd2i, n2i=n2i, measure="MD", data=dat, append=TRUE)    
dat
```

which yields:

```
  study n1i  m1i sd1i n2i  m2i sd2i   yi         vi
1     A  30 15.5  3.2  31 17.9  3.0 -2.4 0.63165591
2     B  60 17.3  1.1  60 18.2  0.9 -0.9 0.03366667
3     C  40 15.1  3.5  44 18.0  2.8 -2.9 0.48443182
```

Variable `yi` provides the mean differences and `vi` the corresponding sampling variances. A basic meta-analysis of these data can then be carried out with:

```
rma(yi, vi, data=dat)
```

which yields:

```
Random-Effects Model (k = 3; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimate of total amount of heterogeneity): 1.0121 (SE = 1.3609)
tau (sqrt of the estimate of total heterogeneity): 1.0061

I^2 (% of total variability due to heterogeneity): 77.21%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):    4.39

Test for Heterogeneity: 
Q(df = 2) = 10.5510, p-val = 0.0051

Model Results:

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub          
 -1.9072   0.6692  -2.8499   0.0044  -3.2189  -0.5956       ** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The value under `estimate` is the estimated average mean difference. Next to it, you get the standard error, the test statistic for the test whether the average mean difference is zero, the corresponding p-value, and the 95% confidence interval bounds.

Above, you also get information about the "heterogeneity" in the effect sizes, that is, variability in the observed effects that is not accounted for by sampling variability alone.